# How to resolve a NoSuchMethodError for org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.SolrRepositoryConfigExtension?

Tags: solr, spring-data

I am trying to extend the sample SpingMongoDB example shared [here](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/) to include Solr Search and Indexing capability. In a nutshell building a SpringData + MongoDB + Spring-Solr application so that any document getting stored in MongoDB would also be stored as an index into Solr.

The following changes were  made to the existing project:
**Added a model class Book.java**

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "book")
public class Book implements Serializable
{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8243145429438016231L;

        @Id
        @Field
        private String id;

        @Field
        private String title;

        @Field
        private String description;
```

Updated the **SpringConfig.xml** file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr.xsd">
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />
    <bean id="mongoTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory"
            ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
    <solr:repositories base-package="com.mkyong.repo" />
    <!-- Define HTTP Solr server -->
    <solr:solr-server id="solrServer"
        url="http://localhost:8983/solr/" />

    <!-- Define Solr template -->
    <bean id="solrTemplate"  class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="solrServer"/>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

And added the below code in the App.java class:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new ClassPathResource("SpringConfig.xml").getPath());
        com.mkyong.repo.BookRepo bookRepo = context.getBean(com.mkyong.repo.BookRepo.class);
        com.mkyong.model.Book hobbit = new com.mkyong.model.Book();
        hobbit.setId("3");
        hobbit.setTitle("Hobbit");
        hobbit.setDescription("Prelude to LOTR");
        //bookRepo.save(hobbit);
        mongoOperation.save(hobbit);
        //solrOperation.saveBean("book", hobbit);       

        System.out.println("#@$@ bookRepo.findOne(3l) ="+bookRepo.findOne(3l));
        System.out.println("@!$@ bookRepo.findByBookTitle(\"Hobbit\") ="+bookRepo.findByBookTitle("Hobbit"));

        context.close();
```

When I run my code main method it gives me the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [SpringConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.SolrRepositoryConfigExtension.registerIfNotAlreadyRegistered(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mkyong.core.App.main(App.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.SolrRepositoryConfigExtension.registerIfNotAlreadyRegistered(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.SolrRepositoryConfigExtension.registerSolrMappingContextIfNotPresent(SolrRepositoryConfigExtension.java:156)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.SolrRepositoryConfigExtension.registerBeansForRoot(SolrRepositoryConfigExtension.java:105)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 14 more
```

Any help would be great. My modified code is available at my github link https://github.com/DipakRai/_springdatasolrWorkspace

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError`=dependencies conflict

Comment: Make sure you're using the same version of the libraries when you're running your application as when you're building and compiling it.

Comment: Doing `maven update` solved my problem